# Working with a multi-line Excel Cell into a C# Program

Tags: c#, excel

My problem seems to be a simple case, but I can't seem to find any answers on it. I'm trying to write a program that will allow me to read Excel files using C# and the Interop method. These Excel files can contain information that has been entered with the use of "Alt-Enter" to  create multiple lines within the cell, each line denoting a different value.

Currently my program spits out the contents of the whole cell, but how do I separate out the multiple values in the single cell, so that I am able to work on the individual values? Sorry if this has a simple answer, I'm a noob at this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Split function:

```
string[] values = ((string) multiLineCell.Value).Split('\n');
```